# Subfig package and tufte class

Tags: captions, subfloats, tufte

I am using the `subfig` package in combination with the [tufte latex](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) class. Unfortunately I did not manage to make it work error free. As discussed in other forums (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=40)), the subfig package alters the caption size of all floats, which can be prevented by using the option `caption=false` when loading the package. However, this somehow confuses the hyperlinks in the document, such that figure and table references are linked to section headers instead of the figures and tables.

Here is an example of the problem I have

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

%\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{This section}
If [caption = false] is used, the hyperrefs go to the section heather above, instead of going to Figure~\ref{testfig} or to Table~\ref{testtab}. If it is not used, the hyperrefs work, but the figure captions are printed with a bigger fontsize than they usually do.

\vspace{10cm}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the test figure}\label{testfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{This is the test table}\label{testtab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I know this is a detail, but I am curious if there is a workaround. I have no clue on how to solve this issue on my own.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Since the `subfig` package is deprecated, you might try the newer `subcaption` package.

Comment: It took me a moment to figure out how to load the `subcaption` package together with the `tufte-latex` class (had to use the option `\captionsetup{compatibility=false}` in the preamble). Then the package can be loaded, but unfortunately the `subcaption` package also changes the font style in figures and tables, so its not help either...

Answer (score 4):

An easy fix for this is to issue a `\phantomsection` at the start of the float you have a reference to:

```
\begin{figure}
  \phantomsection
  % Other figure stuff
  \caption{...}\label{..}
\end{figure}
```

or automate this procedure for *all* figures and tables using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\phantomsection}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\phantomsection}
```

The above "patch" ensures that a hyper anchor is placed at the top of the respective floats; something required by the `\label`-`\ref` system to accurately jump within the PDF.

Comment: This fix seems to work fine when I include the `\phantomsection` command by hand, but the automatic fix did not provide good results. thanks for both answers!

Comment: @yellowcap: What in terms of the automated solution does not provide good results? The only reason it won't provide good results is if you insert a `\label` at an arbitrary position away from a counter increment. For example, you insert (say) `\section{Something}` and then insert a `figure` and then insert the section `\label` near the end of the section (after the `figure`). Typically, you would `\label` where the counter is incremented. Maybe you don't; just a guess.

Comment: sorry I was not clear on that. I played around with the figures some more, and the problem appears when the location of the figures is set using something like `\begin{figure}[t]`. Then the link seems to go to the location of the figure would have without the `[t]` option. I use this option in most figures because tufte-latex usually places the figures within the text.